# Converting one-to-many relationships into relations

Tags: sqlite

Please check this in sqlite  :

agents may make bookings for performers, and performers may also make bookings for themselves. It is only possible for agents to make bookings for functions that involve performers. An agent may be responsible for making bookings for more than one performer. If a performer is represented by an agent, each performer may have only one agent.
[image]

The mandatory nature of the relationship for the agent is shown by the solid circle; the hollow circle indicates an optional relationship for a performer. This means that there must be a relation to represent performers, another relation to represent agents, and a third relation to represent those occasions when performers have booked through agents. The links between performers and agents are shown by having the agent identifier stored against the appropriate performer in the third relation.

Relation: Performers

[image]

Relation: Agents

[image]

Relation: Agent-Performer

[image]

My Question : is it necessary to create third relation ( Agent-Performer) for representing the relationship between the two relations,  Performers and Agents?

what is the problem if i put the foreign key in the many end relation(Performer) and put null in some values in foreign key , without creating third relation ( Agent-Performer)?

PLease, help me in that.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is a many-to-one relationship. A typical way to implement this is for each Performer row to have a foreign key field that holds the value of the related agents primary key.

[image]

So, no, it is not necessary to create a third table to create a one-to-many relationship.

What your third table allows is the creation of a many-to-many relationship:

[image]

Which can be diagrammed like this:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

Comment: Actually, "relation" in the relational data model means "table". See e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Relational_model

Comment: @jhyot ugg fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Agent-Performer table is only needed to represent a many-many relation between Agents and Performers.

The relation you described in text is usually represented with a nullable Agent-id foreign key relation in the Performer table.

The only problem, but that is impossible to enforce in any database schema, is the requirement that each Agent must represent at least one Performer. That requirement will have to be enforces externally, by counting how often an Agent-id occurs in the relation with the Performers and deleting those Agents that have none.

Comment: One might even want to allow an Agent who has no relationships with any Performers as these things can happen IRL.

Comment: @Erik you are right IRL, but the stated requirements don't allow that.

Comment: Yes, perhaps too subtle; my point was to the OP that this might be a kind of problematic design decision (e.g. in the category of overly constrained).  I commented on your post since you called that out clearly.